# textarea's maxlength property without using javascript

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css

i want to use MaxLength behaviour with multiline textbox, which become textarea on rendering.
i need to use Maxlength behaviour without using jquery or javascript.

Comment: @Mattytommo use a rangevalidator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set the `maxlength` attribute on the `textarea`, like so:

```
<textarea maxlength="5"></textarea>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/spaFS/

This will only work in HTML5 documents (and browsers that support it). In HTML4 and older browsers you can't achieve this without JavaScript.

Or for an ASP.NET TextBox, just do:

```
<asp:TextBox MaxLength="5" />
```

Comment: naaah! i need to use asp.net Textbox. and when i set MaxLength="5" and TextMode="Multiline" then on rendering its become textarea as it is a multiline textbox, so textarea does not have Maxlength property. and in the end i can't restrict the user to enter more the specific range! :(

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:TextBox id="tb6" rows="5" MaxLength="20" TextMode="multiline"
runat="server" />
```

Comment: its not working! i already use this. Is there any third party controls that do this?